# How to use $elemMatch query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I tried to filter the data using $elemmatch but it's not correctly working.
My Scenario

**Prod Table**

```
[
  {
    id:1.
    product:[
     {
       id:1,
       name:true
     },
     {
       id:2,
       name:true
     },
     {
      id:3,
      name:false
     }
   ]
  }
]
```

**Query**

```
db.Prod.find(
    {"product.name": true}, 
    {_id: 0, product: {$elemMatch: {name: true}}});
```

**I got Output**

```
[
 {
   id:1.
   product:[
     {
       id:1,
       name:true
     }
  ]
 }
]
```

**Excepted Output**

```
[
 {
   id:1.
   product:[
    {
      id:1,
      name:true
    },
    {
     id:2,
     name:true
    }
   ]
  }
]
```

How to achieve this Scenario and I referred this Link  [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection) and I tried all the answers in this link mentioned. but Still it's not working can give an example query.

Comment: Please format your code with indentation it's very hard to read now

Comment: @  Kannan  I edited code format can pls check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, you probably didn't try the aggregation provided in referenced link, 'cause it perfectly works.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "product.name": true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      product: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$product",
          as: "prod",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$prod.name",
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Will output :

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "product": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": true
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Here's the example.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KYg5WZctuZC)

EDIT : 
[From the doc :](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)

> Usage Considerations
>
> Both the $ operator and the $elemMatch operator project the **first**
>   matching element from an array based on a condition.

Considering this, you cannot achieve what you need with a find query, but only with an aggregation query.

Comment: No, I want only to use find function, not an aggregate function. My scenario use on;y find function

Comment: What's the problem using aggregation?

Comment: actually I am using typescript code So, in many cases I using find the method to retrieve data. but in this case, I can't change the aggregation function. I will maintain standardized code

Comment: So you cannot do this with mongo query, you have to filter your result in TS. See my edited answer.